# Center bootstrap nav bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have very simple list of links in bootstrap navbar:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

but that list is aligned on the left, I need it centered, I tried add inline style

```
style="text-align:center"
```

but it doesn't help.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/NdsaU/

How can I center it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Html

```
<div class="navbar">
   <div class="container">
       <ul class="nav">
           <li><a href="">Link1</a></li>
           <li><a href="">Link2</a></li>
           <li><a href="">Link3</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.navbar { text-align:center; }
.navbar .nav { display:inline-block; float:none; }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NdsaU/1/)